# Why my Nodejs gets automatically upgraded to the latest version of Nodejs after sometime?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a previous version of node installed but after few days it gets automatically updated to the latest version. I do not want it to upgrade itself to a newer version.

Comment: It is probably due to what version you specified in your package.json concerning node

Comment: Please provide more context. How did you install node in the first place? Is it on a global vs project scope? Please post relevant bits, e.g. your `package.json`. We cannot know but only guess what may be causing your issue.

Comment: @k0pernikus i have installed node globally. and in my Package.json. i haven't specified any version number.

Comment: Not specifying any version number is like saying: Always fetch the latest. Everytime you run npm install (esp. if you have no `package.lock`) or npm update it will upgrade to the latest version by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the exact node version in your `package.json` file.

A bit of background, from the [NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning):

> **It's important to communicate the extent of changes** in a new release of code, **because** sometimes **updates can break code that a package needs** (called dependencies).Semantic versioning (semver) is a standard that was designed to solve this problem.

1. From your terminal, type `node --version`; you will get a number formatted as X.X.X
2. Open your `package.json` file and remove any `~` or `^` signs from the node version you want to use so that it won't update to any minor or batch changes.
3. enter `npm install` in your terminal again and you are done.