# Something is automatically installing the latest version of Node on my machine. Can I stop it?

Tags: node.js, auto-update

I've manually installed NodeJS v14 on my machine, but periodically, it gets replaced with the latest version of node, currently v19. There's no indication that this has happened until I check the node version.

I suspect VsCode is automatically installing nodev19, and removing the v14 installation.

Is this right, or is something else the culprit?
If it is VsCode, is there any way to stop it from doing that?

I've searched online, but I don't see anything about node auto updating itself.
Apart from Node itself, I only have the following installed:

1. VsCode
2. Postman
3. Microsoft Teams
4. Slack
5. Git Bash

I've found a similar issue here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49872428/why-my-nodejs-gets-automatically-upgraded-to-the-latest-version-of-nodejs-after) but following the accepted answer doesn't actually install the latest version of node, so I suspect it is something else.